# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined - Trying to grab data from another file

Tags: reactjs, csv, recharts

I'm trying to do this:

```
const convertDistributionToTeams = (arr) => {
    for (let div of DISTRIBUTION) {
        if (arr.includes(div.name)) {
            let idx = arr.indexOf(div.name);
            arr.splice(idx, 1, ...div.teams);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I'm trying to get `div.name` from an already exiting file called `Constant.js`.

I've tried to do the code above but it's just giving me the problem, In Visual Studio Code I click with command on `div.name` and it redirects me to the `Constant.js` file on the `name` line (which actually lets me know that its retrieving the data from there). The problem comes when the code is running I get this:

```
4 | 
   5 | const convertDistributionToTeams = (arr) => {
   6 |     for (let div of DISTRIBUTION) {
>  7 |         if (arr.includes(div.name)) {
   8 |             let idx = arr.indexOf(div.name);
   9 |             arr.splice(idx, 1, ...div.teams);
  10 |         }
```

As you can see `div.name` does not work. I'm really confused at this point.

The full code of the `Chart.js` file is the follwing one:

```
import React from 'react';
import { LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, Tooltip, CartesianGrid, Legend } from 'recharts';
import {DISTRIBUTION} from '../components/ConstantData/Constant'

const convertDistributionToTeams = (arr) => {
    for (let dist of DISTRIBUTION) {
        if (arr.includes(dist.name)) {
            let idx = arr.indexOf(dist.name);
            arr.splice(idx, 1, ...dist.teams);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

const Chart = (props) => {

const teamStatesArr = convertDistributionToTeams(props.teamStates);

    let legendItems = [];
    let dataArr = [];
    let idx = 0;

    for (let teamName of teamStatesArr) {
        legendItems.push(teamName);
        let childArr =[];

        props.data.sort(function(a, b){
            return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);
        });

        for (let i = 0; i < props.data.length; i++) {
            let row = props.data[i];
            if (i > 0 && props.data[i].date === props.data[i - 1].date && props.data[i].externalData) {
                childArr.pop();
            }
            if (props.radioState === 'Both') {
                if (row.home.name === teamName) {
                    childArr.push({x: new Date(row.date), y: parseInt(row.home.pts)});
                } else if (row.visitor.name === teamName) {
                    childArr.push({x: new Date(row.date), y: parseInt(row.visitor.pts)});
                } // Home
            } else if (props.radioState === 'Home') {
                if (row.home.name === teamName) {
                    childArr.push({x: new Date(row.date), y: parseInt(row.home.pts)});
                }
            } else { // Visitor
                if (row.visitor.name === teamName) {
                    childArr.push({x: new Date(row.date), y: parseInt(row.visitor.pts)});
                }
            }
        }

        dataArr.push({key: idx++, data: childArr});
    }

class Chart extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return (
        <LineChart width={1000} height={450} data={dataArr}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
      </LineChart>
    );
  }
}
}


export default Chart;
```

and the one of `Constant.js` is the following one:

```
export const DISTRIBUTION = [
    {
        name: 'Pacific',
        teams: [
            'Golden State Warriors', 'Los Angeles Clippers', 'Los Angeles Lakers', 'Phoenix Suns', 'Sacramento Kings'
        ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Northwest',
        teams: [
            'Denver Nuggets', 'Minnesota Timberwolves', 'Oklahoma City Thunder', 'Portland Trail Blazers', 'Utah Jazz'
        ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Southwest',
        teams: [
            'Dallas Mavericks', 'Houston Rockets', 'Memphis Grizzlies', 'New Orleans Pelicans', 'San Antonio Spurs'
        ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Atlantic',
        teams: [
            'Boston Celtics', 'Brooklyn Nets', 'New York Knicks', 'Philadelphia 76ers', 'Toronto Raptors'
        ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Central',
        teams: [
            'Chicago Bulls', 'Cleveland Cavaliers', 'Detroit Pistons', 'Indiana Pacers', 'Milwaukee Bucks'
        ]
    },

    {
        name: 'Southeast',
        teams: [
            'Atlanta Hawks', 'Charlotte Hornets', 'Miami Heat', 'Orlando Magic', 'Washington Wizards'
        ]
    }
];
```

On the `Principal.js` I'm trying to do the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import FetchCSV from "./FetchCSV"
import Chart from "./Chart"
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import {Selector} from './Selector'
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'
import {Append} from './Append'

export class Principal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            radioState: 'Both',
            data: [],
            teamStates: ['Golden State Warriors'],
        };

        this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getCsvData();
    }

    updateData = (userInput) => {
        let appendArr = this.parseUserInput(userInput);
        appendArr = this.convertArrToObject(appendArr, true);
        let targetArr = [...this.state.data, ...appendArr];
        this.setState({
            data: targetArr,
        });
    }

    parseUserInput = (str) => {
        let arr = str.split('\n');
        let retArr = [];

        for (let item of arr) {
            retArr.push(item.split(','));
        }
        return retArr;
    }

    convertArrToObject = (arr, flag) => {
        let objArr = [];
        for (let row of arr) {
            if (row[0] && row[0] !== 'Date') {
                objArr.push({
                    date: row[0],
                    visitor: {
                        name: row[2],
                        pts: row[3]
                    },
                    home: {
                        name: row[4],
                        pts: row[5]
                    },
                    externalData: flag
                });
            }
        }

        return objArr;
    }

    fetchCsv() {
        return fetch('nba.csv').then(function (response) {
            let reader = response.body.getReader();
            let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');

            return reader.read().then(function (result) {
                return decoder.decode(result.value);
            });
        });
    }

    getData(result) {
        let objArr = this.convertArrToObject(result.data, false);
        this.setState({data: objArr});
    }

    async getCsvData() {
        let csvData = await this.fetchCsv();

        Papa.parse(csvData, {
            complete: this.getData
        });
    }

    handleHomeVisitorRadioButtons = (radioState) => {
        this.setState({radioState: radioState});
    }

    handleTeamStates = (teamStates) => {
        this.setState({teamStates: teamStates});
    }
    render(){
  return (
    <div className="Principal">
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">NBA Season explorer</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
      <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
      <FetchCSV/>
      <div style={{ margin: '30px 0' }} />
      <Append callback={this.updateData}/>
      <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Selector callback={this.handleTeamStates}/>
      <Chart/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

On the `App.js` I can find the following:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Principal} from "./components/Principal"

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        userInput: ''
    }

    handleUserInput = (value) => {
        this.setState({userInput: value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Principal userInput={this.state.userInput}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Error messages:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
convertDistributionToTeams
src/components/Chart.js:7
   4 | 
   5 | const convertDistributionToTeams = (arr) => {
   6 |     for (let dist of DISTRIBUTION) {
>  7 |         if (arr.includes(dist.name)) {
   8 |             let idx = arr.indexOf(dist.name);
   9 |             arr.splice(idx, 1, ...dist.teams);
  10 |         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Print the Array and see its properly formatted or not , because includes will be undefined if you are not using with array or string